# What is a phrasal preposition?

Tags: prepositions, syntactic-analysis

I was reading [an article by GrammarBook.com](http://data.grammarbook.com/blog/definitions/into-vs-in-to-expanded/#comment-692100) when the moderators used a term I had never heard of.

> *Out of is a phrasal preposition.*

What is exactly a phrasal preposition? Is it when a preposition is forced to immediately follow another preposition?

While I'm at it, are *in front of* and *on top of* phrasal prepositions, too? Maybe you haven't noticed, but *on top* and *in front* both always take *of* when there is a noun.

> *I am on top **[of you]**.*
>
> *I am in front **[of these people]**.*
>
> *I am out **[of here]**.*
>
> *I walked out **[of the building]**.*

So what's up with this phrasal preposition business? Anybody familiar with the term?

Comment: As a native speaker I have never had to learn English from a grammar book. Hence I have never heard of "phrasal prepositions". But what you are saying sounds perfectly logical.

Answer (score 1):

No. A phrasal preposition is a phrase that mimics a preposition, such as "rather than" or "in lieu of."

On top of, in front of, and out of are phrasal prepositions because they are phrases that act as prepositions.

Comment: If all three are phrasal prepositions, then why did you say, "No"?

Comment: Wait, nvm. I see what you mean now.